# How to check if data exists in a record before performing an action in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, qr-code

I made an app to scan qr code. I want the data scanned from the qr code(which will be a number like 2300, 2301, 2302) to be compared to a column called ID in the sqlite database. Some of the values in the sqlite database for column ID are 2301, 2302, 2303. I want that the data scanned will be compared to the values in ID and if they match an action will be performed. If not an error message will be shown. If the qr code has value 2301, then the action will be perform. If it is 8900(a number not in the database) it displays a message:Student not found. I would also like to clarify that the scannedData is not being entered into the sqlite database but sent to a google script link. The sqlite database contains a list of students. I want that if the scanned data is not similar to nay ID in the sqlite database then the sannedData will not be sent to google app script destination.
This my database code for activity DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "SURNAME";
public static final String COL_4 = "MARKS";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS TEXT)");
}
```

Below is the code i want to modify to check if it is in the database. This is another activity called MainActivity.

```
    public class ArrivalTime extends AppCompatActivity {

    String scannedData;
    Button scanBtn;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    //DatabaseHelper myDb;
//------------------------------------------------------------


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arrival_time);
        final Activity activity = this;
        scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);
        //-------------------------------------------------------
     //  myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //---------------------------------------------------------

        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Place barcode in window to Scan it");
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }

        });

    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result= IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        if(result!=null){
            scannedData = result.getContents();
            if(scannedData != null){
                // here we need to handle scanned data
               // Cursor c = myDb.getId(String);
               // if(c.getCount() == 0) {
                    // show message
                 //   Toast.makeText(ArrivalTime.this,"Student doesn't exist in database",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 //   return;
                //}
                new SendRequest().execute();

            }
            else{

            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        protected void onPreExecute(){}

        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0){

            try{
                URL url = new URL("https://script.google.com/macros/s/ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt/exec");

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

                postDataParams.put("sdata",scannedData);
                Log.e("params", postDataParams.toString());

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";

                    while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return sb.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            String key= itr.next();
            Object value = params.get(key);

            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the function to check if the scanned data in not null and that it exists in the database. I tried just doing    if(scannedData != null && scanned==id) but i'm not sure how to call database data from another activity and perform a comparison

I've been given an example below but it assumes that i'm checking if there is a similar value as whatever's been scanned so that it can be entered into the sqlite database which is not  what i want.

Any suggestions.

Comment: i think you want to check data using ID Column..

Comment: Yeah. That's what i want to do

Comment: ok check the answer . if data exist ti will return true.

Comment: have you done ? i have updated some code..please check it..

Comment: if you feel any problem to do you may ask me...

Comment: do i add this inside the if scannedData!=null and am i supposed to use a different name other than the one for the database i created in this part: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: you can add this method inside DatabaseHelper and check it before scanner, if it return true then you start scaning..

Comment: I wanted to check after scanning that way the retrieved data can be compared to whatevers in the database

Comment: No problem you can check it after scanning finish..

Comment: after scanning you just pass the value ..

Comment: Sir, its still scanning the data that isn't in the database

Comment: Should i somehow link the message to mainactivity with the if(scannedData!=null)

Comment: can you check boolean method return value?

Comment: can you provide me getId method call code..

Comment: You can check  if(scannedData != null)...

Comment: public Boolean getId(String id) {
        boolean rValue = false;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "  + TABLE_NAME + " where "+ COL_1 +" = ? " ;

        SQLiteDatabase datab = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = datab.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{id});


        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // Data Is Exist;
                rValue = true;
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        datab.close();
        c.close();

        return rValue;

    }

Comment: I changed the QliteDatabase name to datab cause there was another cursor with db name that

Comment: do you want to get all data & check after geting data..

Comment: Oh no that was another curser for reading all the data. I just wanted to show you that there are two cursers now that i've tried to add yours which is why i changed the name db in the code you posted to datab. You can ignore it and focus on getId method

Comment: It was just in case it interfered with your code so i wanted to let you know that there was another cursor in my DBHelper

Comment: I added something in the question i posted. Please check if i'm right

Answer (score 0):

You can check bellow like..

```
  public Boolean getId(String id) {
   boolean rValue = false;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "  + TABLE_NAME + " where "+ COL_1 +" = ? " ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{id});


    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // Data Is Exist;
            rValue = true;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    c.close();

    return rValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is very simple,you have to make a select query using a given value for the ID column and check the Cursor.getCount() method like this.
`Cursor.getCount(); // returns number of rows from this query`.
if it returns 0 so there are some rows in there that means the ID do exist

```
public boolean Contains(String ID) {
    Cursor cursor = null;

    cursor = db.rowQuery("SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE ID === ? ", new String[]{ID});
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What about in the if function if(scannedData != null). Is what i've written correct to compare the scanned data to whatevers in the db

Comment: I did not use this before ,I always use my solution and it was tested and worked perfectly for all my projects.and it's so easy and optimized too.

Comment: How do i call the method to the onActivityresult method before new SendRequest().execute() action is performed. It wont automatically check if the value is scannedData is siilar to anything in the database